# How much countable additivity does asymptotic density have?

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory

For $A\subseteq \mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ let $d(A)$ be the "density" defined by
$$
d(A) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|A \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|} n \tag 1
$$
whenever that limit exists.  This is finitely additive but clearly not countably additive.

I expect there will be theorems that say that for some sort of $\text{“ }$**well behaved**$\text{ ''}$ sequences $(A_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ of subsets of $\mathbb N$ one has
$$
d\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k \right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty d(A_k).
$$
Thus the sequence $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\ldots$ is not "well behaved".  Any such theorem would have to specify which sort of good behavior is intended.